# Layout gravity is not centered in custom FrameLayout View

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Custom Layout extending FrameLayout with custom XML. Parent children views have `android:layout_gravity` and `android:gravity` set to `center`. It is looking exactly as It should in layout preview, but in App, `TextView` and `ProgressBar` is not centered correctly. It is centered horizontally but not vertically.

Any suggestions?

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonParent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buttonText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Output from LayoutInspector

[image]

UPDATE - SOLUTION:

I found out solution. I have to add this to my class extending `FrameLayout`

```
val rootParams = LayoutParams(buttonWidth.toInt(), buttonHeight.toInt())
rootParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
layoutParams = rootParams
```

It looks like that FrameLayout parent inside XML inflated layout is not considered as parent. Parent is not even visible in XML it is class where I inflated XML. I have to access parent parameter by `this.parameter` not in XML.

Comment: your parent `FrameLayout` height is wrap_content make it `match_parent`

Comment: It is wrap content because button is not intended to be only match_parent. It can have custom width

Comment: You haven't given `layout_gravity` and `gravity` as `center` to the FrameLayout

Comment: Changed FrameLayout to match_parent and add gravity to FrameLayout and it is still same

Comment: have you given both `layout_gravity` and `gravity` as center ?

Comment: Yes I set both.

Comment: Can you show the output image?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` instead of  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your `FrameLayout`, like following.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_gravity="center` to your `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Or set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to your `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```